# Create a two color circle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create two half circles (each with a different color) which together form one circle. Something like this

[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u78bQ/3911/)

I created this using 2 elements and a bit of css:

```
<span class="circle-part half-left-circle"></span>
<span class="circle-part half-right-circle"></span>
```

and

```
$size: 100px;
$border: 20px;

...

.half-right-circle {
    border-top-right-radius: $size + $border;
    border-bottom-right-radius: $size + $border;
    border: $border solid green;
    border-left: 0;
}

.half-left-circle {
    border-top-left-radius: $size + $border;
    border-bottom-left-radius: $size + $border;
    border: $border solid red;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Although this is exactly what I need, I was wondering if this can be achieved with just one html element (without pseudo elements of course :) ?

Comment: @musefan am not really sure why you thing this is a bad question or why his code is not relevant ... he provided a solution using two elements and he's wondering if something is possible using a reduced code and rely on only one element to achieve the same? what is the issue with this? it's a legit question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Question is how to do A, sample code is how to do B. A is not the same as B. Just because they are similar, does not make them the same problem/solution. OP should include code that attempts to solve the problem they want solving, not code that solves a different problem

Comment: @musefan well, this is your opinion :) ... for me A and B are the same here. Maybe the asker doesn't have the needed experience to achieve this with less of code and he shared his attempt using his knowledge and he's asking `I was wondering if this can be achieved with just one html ` ... So he's not asking for `do this for me with only one element`, so it's not about solving a problem here [because it's already solved] and the answer can be YES or NO and in both cases we may have explanation of why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working snippet of what I'll do, using `border`:

- `%` values instead of `px` for `border-radius`, it simplifies a lot!
- `border-color` to add the correct color for each side.
- `transform: rotate(45deg);` to turn it like you want.

```css
body{
  background: #ccc;
}

.halves-circle{
  background: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: green green red red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="halves-circle">
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

We could use some CSS variables too, if you want to make many of them:

```css
body{
  background: #ccc;
}

.halves-circle{
  background: #fff;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  border: var(--border) solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: green green red red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#hc1{
  --size: 100px;
  --border: 20px;
}

#hc2{
  --size: 60px;
  --border: 30px;
}

#dot{ /* We can even do this! */
  --size: 0px;
  --border: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="halves-circle" id="hc1"></div>
<div class="halves-circle" id="hc2"></div>
<div class="halves-circle" id="dot"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice, this is what I was looking for, thnx!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Thanks, I'm glad to help. :) I've added another solution with CSS variables.

Comment: @TakitIsy I also tried your code. But the result is not like your result. The colored areas are angled to left side.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more simple solution with only 2 gradient and less of code:

```css
.circle {
  margin:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
      radial-gradient(circle at center,white 60%,transparent 60.5%),
      linear-gradient(to right,red 50%,green 0);
}

body {
 background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using 60.5%? (I think I know, but I want to be sure!)

Comment: @TakitIsy let's say it's one of the drawbacks of gradient, when you use 60% or less you will have a hard-color stop and the edge will be jagged so to avoid this we should have a small difference between stoping values to create a little blur effect that will cover the bad effect.

Comment: That's what I thought. That's kind of an anti-aliasing trick! Nice.

Comment: @TakitIsy yes gradient aren't anti-aliasing ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.circle {
 margin: 25px 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 50%,100% 100%, 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), 
                    linear-gradient(360deg, green 100%, lightgrey 100%),
                    linear-gradient(360deg, red 100%, lightgrey 100%);
  background-position: center center, left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66r7nj4x/

Comment: Wow, this one is nice too. It is amazing what can be done with the `background` css property. Thnx

Comment: You should color the `body` background, so that we'll be able to see the background-color of the circle. :)